# Python : threads; SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to run a certain function as a thread, but I get

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

And I do not understand why :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import arduinoReadThread
import arduinoWriteThread
import socket
import thread

bolt = 0
socketArray=list()
HOST ="localhost"
PORT1 =50000
PORT2 =50001

def readAndParseArgv():
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) #create an INET, STREAMing socket
    s.bind((HOST,PORT1)) #bind to that port
    print "test"
    s.listen(2) #listen for user input and accept 1 connection at a time.
    socketArray.append(s)
    s2=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) #create an INET, STREAMing socket
    s2.bind((HOST,PORT2)) #bind to that port
    print "test"
    s2.listen(2) #listen for user input and accept 1 connection at a time.
    socketArray.append(s2)

def socketFunctionWrite1():
    print threadName
    client, address = s1.accept()
    while(bolt == 0):
        print "Writing connections"
        if len(s1ToWriteList) > 0:
            client.send(s1ToWriteList.pop(0))

def socketFunctionRead1():
    client, address = s2.accept()
    while(bolt == 0):
        f = client.recv(1024)
        print "reading connection"
        s1ToWriteList.append(f)
        print len(s1ToWriteList)

def socketFunctionWrite2():
    client, address = s2.accept()
    while(bolt == 0):
        print "Writing connections"
        if len(s2ToWriteList) > 0:
            client.send(s2ToWriteList.pop(0))

def socketFunctionRead2():
    client, address = s1.accept()
    while(bolt == 0):
        f = client.recv(1024)
        print "reading connection"
        s2ToWriteList.append(f)
        print len(s2ToWriteList)

def shutDown():
    test = raw_input("Quit ?")
    if(test =="y"):
        bolt = 1
    else:
        shutDown()

thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead1,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionWrite1,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead2,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionWrite2,())

readAndParseArgv()
spreadSockets()
```

I want to open these sockets as threads. I do not get why I get the non-keyword error, as the function I want to run as a thread is `socketFunctionRead1`

error :

```
  File "pythonbis.py", line 79
    thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead1,())
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: can you paste the full error stack? What line exactly triggers the error?

Comment: done :), sry I did not do this earlier

Comment: NP. Anyhow I got it even before you did! See my edited answer! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247754/2149425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) the the signature for the `thread.start_new_thread` call is:

```
thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])
```

The way you are calling it is:

```
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead1,())
```

As you can see you are passing a named (keyword) argument **before** the non-named one: you are saying `target=socket...` before `()`.

**EDIT:** just to clarify. The solution is either to remove the keyword to the first argument or to add it to the second.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

```
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead1,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionWrite1,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionRead2,())
thread.start_new_thread(target=socketFunctionWrite2,())
```

Needs to be

```
thread.start_new_thread((),target=socketFunctionRead1)
thread.start_new_thread((),target=socketFunctionWrite1)
thread.start_new_thread((),target=socketFunctionRead2)
thread.start_new_thread((),target=socketFunctionWrite2)
```

You can't have positional arguments *after* keyword arguments, which is true for any method in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *target* keyword:

```
thread.start_new_thread(socketFunctionRead1, ())
```

Here is the [documented syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread):

> thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])¶ Start a new thread
>   and return its identifier. The thread executes the function function
>   with the argument list args (which must be a tuple). The optional
>   kwargs argument specifies a dictionary of keyword arguments. When the
>   function returns, the thread silently exits. When the function
>   terminates with an unhandled exception, a stack trace is printed and
>   then the thread exits (but other threads continue to run).

The reason for the error is covered in the [tutorial section on keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).  In short, keyword arguments cannot precede positional arguments because the position becomes ambiguous.