# Python: SyntaxError: non-keyword after keyword arg

Tags: python

When I run the following code

```
def regEx1():
  os.chdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/myFiles")
  files = os.listdir(".")
  os.mkdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/FilesWithRegEx")
  regex_txt = input("Please enter the website your are looking for:")
  for x in (files):
    inputFile = open((x), encoding = "utf8", "r")
    content = inputFile.read()
    inputFile.close()
    regex = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE)
    if re.search(regex, content)is not None:
      shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/FilesWithRegEx")
```

I get the following error message which points to the first line after the for loop.

```
      ^

SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: The encoding is meant to go after the `'r'` I think

Answer (score 79):

It's just what it says:

```
inputFile = open((x), encoding = "utf8", "r")
```

You have specified `encoding` as a keyword argument, but `"r"` as a positional argument.  You can't have positional arguments after keyword arguments.  Perhaps you wanted to do:

```
inputFile = open((x), "r", encoding = "utf8")
```

Answer (score 2):

To really get this clear, here's my for-beginners answer:
You inputed the arguments in the **wrong order.**
A keyword argument has this style:

```
nullable=True, unique=False
```

A fixed parameter should be defined: True, False, etc.
A non-keyword argument is different:

```
name="Ricardo", fruit="chontaduro"
```

This syntax error asks you to first put `name="Ricardo"` and all of its kind (non-keyword) **before** those like `nullable=True.`

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword)[non-keyword](/questions/tagged/non-keyword)[syntax-error](/questions/tagged/syntax-error)

Comment: Please, refer to this tutorial for more info: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument