# What's wrong with this buttonbox?

Tags: python

```
42 key = easygui.buttonbox(msg="Enter your message. Your current message is", msg,
                           choices=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
                                    "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",   "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", 
                                    "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Space", ".", "I'm Done"])
```

There's an error in your program:

> **SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg** (C:/Python25/Cipher.py, line 42)

I think the bold part is wrong, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247754/1068495). Fix it by changing the arrangement of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If this documentation is still up to date, your `msg` variable for `title` is probably causing your issue
http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial/easygui_pydoc.html#-buttonbox

```
easygui.buttonbox(msg="Enter your message. Your current message is", msg, choices=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",   "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Space", ".", "I'm Done"])
```

It should probably be:

```
easygui.buttonbox(msg="", title=msg, choices=["..."])
```

or this if `msg` wasn't supposed to be added to `title`.

```
easygui.buttonbox(msg="", title="Something", choices=["..."])
```

If I remember Python correctly, you do not need to specify `variable=` unless you are changing the order or skipping a prior parameter. Once you say `variable=`, you need say it for all parameters after that.

*Note: Leave everything else you had, just correct the title parameter. I cleared the other parameters to make this readable.*

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I mixed the syntax of how I send my arguments to the functions ....

Lets say that this is the function declaration:

```
def buttonbox(title="", msg="", choices="")
```

All arguments are optional

But you called it with a mix of:

```
easygui.buttonbox(title="enter your msg", msg, choices="some choices")
```

Like calling a function with

```
func(a="",b,c="bla",d,e,f,g="b2") etc ..
```

So it should be either argument=value:

```
easygui.buttonbox(title="enter your msg", msg=msg, choices="some choices")
```

OR simply value,value,value:

```
easygui.buttonbox("enter your msg",msg,"some choices")
```

This is what solved it for me ...maybe others will find it useful.