# Pyinstaller and Kivy will not install

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I got an error when using Pyinstaller to make my Kivy app an exe. I have been following [this](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html) tutorial on how to do it, but I get this error when I build the spec file:

```
C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Encryption>pyinstaller Encryption.spec
164 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.0
165 INFO: Python: 3.4.3
166 INFO: Platform: Windows-8-6.2.9200
186 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.0', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 99, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 47, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\paolo\Downloads\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 680, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 33
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

I honestly have no clue what any of that means, since none of it actually includes the spec file itself. I edited my spec file to what the Kivy guide says, and it looks like

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_hooks
import os
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\paolo\\Documents\\PythonProjects\\KivyEncryption\\KivyMain.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\paolo\\Downloads\\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\\Encryption'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             excludes=None,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
             win_private_assemblies=None,
             cipher=block_cipher, **get_hooks())
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Encryption',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='Encryption',
               Tree('C:\Users\paolo\Documents\PythonProjects\KivyEncryption\\'),
               Tree([f for f in os.environ.get('KIVY_SDL2_PATH', '').split(';') if 'bin' in f][0]))
```

I've tested my Kivy app before doing this, and it works as it should; so I guess the question is what am I doing wrong? I've searched all over the web for that error, but I've found nothing related to Kivy. I am using the latest version of Kivy portable off their website (1.9.0) and using Windows 10.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this error before in a non-Kivy context. It just means that your parameters in a function/method call are in the incorrect order. Keyword parameters (i.e. those beginning `keyword=`) must come after all parameters that don't have a keyword. For example, looking at your `COLLECT` part, the last two parameters look like non-keyword parameters but they've come after some keywords. Did you see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247732/python-syntaxerror-non-keyword-after-keyword-arg)?

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work...