# Dark image on PyGame

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, pygame, pygame-surface

We are using a Raspberry Pi + Python 3.4 + PyGame to capture an image from a specific USB webcam. We use this simple code to capture (it works ok):

```
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0],(1280,720))
cam.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
webcamImage = cam.get_image()
```

The problem is: the image is very dark. If we connect the webcam to our PC (Windows or Linux, no differences) and we use a common software to grab the image (Skype, Chees,.. no differences) we have a clear and shiny image. Check it out:

[image: From PC] FromPC

[image: From PyGame] From PyGame

With Pygame we have an image very dark. We tried to solve this with the function:

```
cam. set_controls(hflip = True, vflip = True, 10)
```

but we have an error. Ok, we tried with PIL.ImageEnhance but we had no good results. Can we help us to understand how to manage that situation? Thanks.

Comment: What was the problem with `cam.set_controls(hflip = True, vflip = True, 10)` ?

Comment: Hi @LPK, here is the error. If we set (after or before cam.start(), no differences) this: **cam.set_controls(hflip = False, vflip = False, 10)**, we have **SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg**. If we do cam.get_controls() we have **(False, False, 0)**

Comment: Also, we noticed that we not have white colors as the image from PC, just pure colors.

Comment: try cam.set_controls(True, True, 10) instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247732/python-syntaxerror-non-keyword-after-keyword-arg

Comment: Another error: **SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported!**. We not found a solution for that.

Comment: We think this is an hard problem. We have to move on with our work, so we abandon the goal of finding a solution to this problem. Thank you for your efforts.