# choice() function argument: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, random

```
tup_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
weight_list = [0.5,0.6,0.1,0.7]   
draw = choice(tup_list, sample_size_d, replace=False, weight_list)
```

when I try to run it, I get error: SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
How could I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: SyntaxError: non-keyword after keyword arg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247732/python-syntaxerror-non-keyword-after-keyword-arg)

Answer (score 0):

Here `weight_list` is a non-keyword arg. When calling a function in Python, all keyword arguments (key=value type) should follow all non-keyword arguments. Your call to `choice` should be like:

```
draw = choice(tup_list, sample_size_d, weight_list, replace=False)
```

See this question:
[Python normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)